# solve the recurrence relation $h_n - 0h_{n - 1} - 3h_{n - 2} + 2h_{n - 3}= 0$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

$h_n - 0h_{n - 1} - 3h_{n - 2} + 2h_{n - 3}= 0$

$h_0=2, h_1=0, h_2=7$, and n≥3
is given

here is what I did

$x^3-3x+2=0$

$h_n=a1^n+b(-2)^n$

roots of the polynomial are 1 and -2 but there are 3 equations($h_0,h_1,h_2$) and 2 variables so we need 3 three roots. what is the third root? how do you solve this type of recurrences?

Comment: In general, if the characteristic polynomial has multiple roots, search for solutions of the form $n\lambda^n$ (or $n^a\lambda^n$ if the roots have multiplicity $a+1$) Thus, for instance, $a_n=n$ is a solution to $a_n=2a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}$.

Comment: $x=1$ is a double root

Answer (score 1):

What you did is correct.

The characteristic equation is

$ x^3 - 3 x + 2 = 0 $

By inspection, one of the roots is $x = 1 $.  By synthetic division,

$ (x^3 - 3 x + 2) = (x - 1) (x^2 + x - 2) = (x - 1)^2 (x + 2) $

So the roots are $ 1, 1, -2 $

Therefore, the solution to this homogeneous difference equation is

$ h_n = A + B n + C (-2)^n $

From the initial conditions $h_0, h_1, h_2$ the constants $A,B,C$ can be computed.

We have

$h_0 = 2 = A + C $

$ h_1 = 0 = A + B - 2 C $

$ h_2 = 7 = A + 2 B + 4 C $

And these equations solve to $ A = B = C = 1 $

Hence, the sequence is

$ h_n = 1 + n + (-2)^n $